# Trying to deploy app on openshift. "program node app.js exited with code 8". Can't figure out what's going on

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, deployment, openshift

I'm pretty new at this. This is my first time trying to deploy an app in a production environment. It works totally fine locally (and of course with local environment variables instead of Openshift's environment variables). But on openshift I just can't get it to run. It always responds with "503 Service Temporarily unavailable". I've been tinkering with it for hours, and looking everywhere for a solution, but nothing is working.

Here's what I have in my index.js file (it's just a simple mongodb utilizing to-do list. And like I said, it works fine locally, but yes, it's very messy. Like I said. I'm new):

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

var dbUrl = 'mongodb://$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT/todo_list';

var result;
var list;

var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride(function(req, res){
  if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
    // look in urlencoded POST bodies and delete it
    var method = req.body._method
    delete req.body._method
    return method
  }
}));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

function updateList(res){
    MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db){
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        var list = db.collection('list');
        list.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs){
            res.render('index', { title: 'To do:', list: docs });
        });
    });
};

//routes

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    updateList(res);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var data = req.body.words;
    MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db){
        var list = db.collection('list');
        list.insert({ task: data }, updateList(res));
    });
});

app.delete('/:id', function(req, res){
    var removal = req.params.id;
    MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db){
        var list = db.collection('list');
        list.remove({ _id: ObjectId(removal)}, updateList(res));
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});

var server = app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening');
});

module.exports = server;
```

And then here's what's logged out to me:

```
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/var/lib/openshift/<key>/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/<key>/app-root/runtime/repo/index.js:66:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
DEBUG: Program node index.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node index.js'
```

I'm at a loss. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to bind to the OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP environment variable. This can be done in the second argument of app.listen, like as follows:

```
var ipAddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP
var server = app.listen(port, ipAddress, function(){
  console.log('listening');
});
```

If you don't do this, the default IP address will be 0.0.0.0 which won't work on Openshift

Comment: Ideally, you will also provide an alternate IP address and port for your development environment such as:

var ipAddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || 127.0.0.1
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000